# Hide mat-rows in mat-table when data is loading

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to hide the rows of a MatTable when its loading.

I can't do this: (see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mw8kah?embed=1&file=app/table-pagination-example.html) for entire code)

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</div>
```

as MatTable will throw all kinds of errors :(

I can't put `*ngIf="!isLoading"` inside the `MatRow` as it already have a structural directive.

I would like to avoid CSS trickery.

What am I not seeing? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the "trick" was to use `[hidden]`

`<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [hidden]="isLoading"></tr>`

However I didn't end up using this solution as it made the table "jumpy". Instead I opted to put a spinner in the table footer.

Comment: It doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 5):

Can't use two structural directives on one element. use `ng-container`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

<ng-container>
```

Comment: That's more like it :) However MatTable doesn't love it. I've updated the StackBlitz with the changes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mw8kah

Answer (score 1):

I would remove data on the time of loading. No trickery there.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now as a "workaround". However I don't like it as gives the `datasource` display responsibility which it shouldn't care one bit about.

Comment: And thats the way to go. No need to overcomplicate simple things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-container`

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  ...
  <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </ng-container>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: Material is a bit inflexible here and complains in this case with "rowDef is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<div class="course">

    <div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async">
        <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    </div>

    <mat-table class="lessons-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
        ....
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

It will also add a nice spinner when data is loading.

Comment: While that is a solution. It doesn't exactly solve the issue stated.

Comment: @Snæbjørn so maybe just `<table mat-table *ngIf="!dataSource.loading$">`?

Comment: that would hide the table headers resulting in an odd looking view. You'd expect a loading thing to be inside the table not remove it entirely

Answer (score 0):

You could control your displayedColumns with the isLoading flag.

```
get displayedColumns() {
  return this.isLoading ? [] : ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
}
```

Your template would be simple again and it is well testable.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is what was suggested, but you have to add css to make it work.

`So the "trick" was to use [hidden]

However I didn't end up using this solution as it made the table "jumpy". Instead I opted to put a spinner in the table footer.`

`mat-row[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}`